# What resolution does Google use while crawling a site with responsive/adaptive design?

Tags: googlebot, responsive-webdesign

I use conditional loading and media queries, JS, and CSS techniques for building responsive/adaptive designed websites.

The HTML output for these sites depends on the number of horizontal and vertical pixels of the users's browser window.

What resolution does Google use while indexing sites, which impacts the HTML output that's returned?

Comment: How can the "HTML output" depend on the user's screen size? It's not sent to the server.

Comment: DisgruntledGoat: I use conditional loading and/or media queries. That means that if a user opens a page in 1280x1024px screen he/she will get a different source code than he/she had got by opening the same page in 600x800px screen. The question is about that which resolution Google "sees" the site. If it's a duplicate question and already has the answer please direct me there because I cannot find the same qeuestion (so the answer).

Comment: Media queries do not change the HTML output.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat Thank you for the info! So display:none and media queries combo itself doesn't work thay way. But conditional loading do change the HTML output. [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.matchMedia) MatchMedia loads the element only when the given conditions are present. If these conditions are a given range of resolutions, how can I know that will Googlebot "see" it's content or not?

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat I just see that at the top of the page a link appeared with the corresponding topik. Ok, topik closed. :)